# java.io.IOException: Lease timeout of 0 seconds expired

Tags: hadoop

I'm getting the following warning while running my mapreduce jobs under cd4.

> java.io.IOException: Lease timeout of 0 seconds expired.
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.abort(DFSOutputStream.java:1700)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.closeAllFilesBeingWritten(DFSClient.java:652)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.renewLease(DFSClient.java:604)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.renew(LeaseRenewer.java:411)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.run(LeaseRenewer.java:436)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.access$700(LeaseRenewer.java:70)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer$1.run(LeaseRenewer.java:297)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Any idea what this means?

Comment: Hi @kumar, 

I've run into same issue, did you find the root cause of this exception and fix it?

Comment: Perhaps the comment in this related question is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855384/spark-streaming-java-io-ioexception-lease-timeout-of-0-seconds-expired