# Spark Streaming - java.io.IOException: Lease timeout of 0 seconds expired

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming, kerberos, cloudera

I have spark streaming application using checkpoint writing on HDFS.

Has anyone know the solution? 
Previously we were using the kinit to specify principal and keytab and got the suggestion to specify these via `spark-submit` command instead `kinit` but still this error and cause spark streaming application down.

```
spark-submit --principal sparkuser@HADOOP.ABC.COM --keytab /home/sparkuser/keytab/sparkuser.keytab --name MyStreamingApp --master yarn-cluster --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC --conf "spark.eventLog.enabled=true" --conf "spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled=true" --conf "spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown=true" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC --class com.abc.DataProcessor myapp.jar
```

I see multiple occurrences of following exception in logs and finally SIGTERM 15 that kills the executor and driver. We are using CDH 5.5.2

> 2016-10-02 23:59:50 ERROR SparkListenerBus LiveListenerBus:96 -
>   Listener EventLoggingListener threw an exception
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
>                  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>                  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener$$anonfun$logEvent$3.apply(EventLoggingListener.scala:148)
>                  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener$$anonfun$logEvent$3.apply(EventLoggingListener.scala:148)
>                  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
>                  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.logEvent(EventLoggingListener.scala:148)
>                  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.onUnpersistRDD(EventLoggingListener.scala:184)
>                  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus$class.onPostEvent(SparkListenerBus.scala:50)
>                  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.onPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:31)
>                  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.onPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:31)
>                  at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus$class.postToAll(ListenerBus.scala:56)
>                  at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus.postToAll(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:37)
>                  at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:79)
>                  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1135)
>                  at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1.run(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:63)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Lease timeout of 0 seconds expired.
>                  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.abort(DFSOutputStream.java:2370)
>                  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.closeAllFilesBeingWritten(DFSClient.java:964)
>                  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.renewLease(DFSClient.java:932)
>                  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.renew(LeaseRenewer.java:423)
>                  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.run(LeaseRenewer.java:448)
>                  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.access$700(LeaseRenewer.java:71)
>                  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer$1.run(LeaseRenewer.java:304)
>                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Do you see the issue on **startup**, or at the time of **ticket renewal**? For the latter case *"... In practice, due to several bugs (HDFS-9276, SPARK-11182) ... [for] HDFS in HA mode ... HDFS cache must be disabled"* http://mkuthan.github.io/blog/2016/09/30/spark-streaming-on-yarn/